# Running a GNU parallel command using python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, multiprocessing, subprocess, gnu-parallel

Here is a simple GNU parallel command that creates a file called "example_*i*.txt" inside an existing directory called "example_*i*". It does this four times, for *i* from 1 to 4, with one job per core:

```
parallel -j 4 'cd example_{} && touch example_{}.txt' ::: {1..4}
```

Not very exciting, I know. The problem appears when I try to run this via python (v3.9) using the subprocess module as follows:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "parallel -j 4 'cd example_{} && touch example_{}.txt' ::: {1..4}"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

When doing so I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to example_{1..4}
```

It looks like using the python subprocess call, bash is not triggering the call correctly as a GNU parallel command. Instead, it is substituting the `{1..4}` explicitly rather than dividing it up into four jobs.

I also tried this with the less advisable `os.system(cmd)` syntax and got back the same error.

PS: For context, this question stems from me trying to use [UQpy](https://github.com/SURGroup/UQpy) (the [RunModel module](https://github.com/SURGroup/UQpy/blob/master/src/UQpy/RunModel.py) in particular) for uncertainty quantification of a Fortran code that was handed to me. Although this is not directly related to the question, it is relevant because I would like to know how to get this working using *these* tools as I am not at liberty to change them.

Comment: I think you either need to ensure `subprocess.run()` uses `bash`, or avoid *"bashisms"* by replacing `{1..4}` with `1 2 3 4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Mark Setchell's comment, indeed it appears that `bash` is not used by default on POSIX as can be seen in the [documentation for subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). This is solved by explicitly telling `subprocess` to use `bash` by re-writting my python code snippet as:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "parallel -j 4 'cd example_{} && touch example_{}.txt' ::: {1..4}"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

It should be noted that although the argument `executable` is here being used in the `subprocess.run()` call, it is not directly a part of this class. The `executable` argument is actually part of the `subprocess.Popen()` class, but it is accessible to `subprocess.run()` by the `**other_popen_kwargs` argument.